# What does the idiom be such as to infinitive mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> Education proceeds ultimately from the patterns furnished by institutions, customs, and laws.  Only in a just state will these be such as to give the right education.

(Source: Democracy and Education By John Dewey)

I think the second sentence means that the patterns (=these) will give the right education only in a just state.  Did I understand the sentence correctly?  Could you please help me clarify it?

Comment: No, "these" refers to the whole phrase:  "patterns furnished by institutions, customs and laws".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your interpretation.

Re-arranging to avoid the inversion of the verb and subject, and replacing the pronoun with its reference, gives

> [The patterns furnished by institutions, customs and laws] will be [such as to give the right education] [only in a just state].

Paraphrasing:

> If your country is not fair, then the government, culture and laws will not be the right kind to give a good education.

Or more broadly

> Bad government makes bad schools.

Answer (score 1):

[such] [as] [to give]

[of a kind] [that] [gives]

In these synonymous constructions, **as**, in modern English, takes an infinitival complement (or a modal + infinitive) and **that** takes a clause with a tensed verb.  But **such as to** is falling out of use. It has a Victorian flavor.

Answer (score 0):

*X is such as to Y* = *X creates/permits/facilitates/makes the conditions that allow Y'ing*.

> Only in a just state will these be such as to give the right education.
>
> Only in a just state will these create the conditions that allow giving the right education.